# Why is 0x82 smaller than 0x80?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, comparison, signed

I'm trying to optimise a String class for a college class exercise. 
Normal strings get stored as char* and a size_t for length. sizeof(String) is 8 and it should stay like this. Yet if I only have strings with 7 or less chars (or 6 if you consider the null terminator), instead of using pointers I want to store them in the pointer/size_t bytes directly.

For this I have two structs, one for the char* and size_t and one with an array of 8 chars (bytes). Both I place in an union and give the String class a member of said union.

To determine if a string is a normal string, or a short one I use the most significant bit of the length size_t or byte[7]. If byte[7] is bigger or equal 128 (or 0x80) it's a short string and the characters are stored in the bytes directly. The length is then stored in the remaining bits of byte[7].

That's the theory so far. The normal string bit is already implemented and I'm now trying to implement the short string bit. The problem I have right now is with the following bit of code:

```
inline const char* c_str(void) const
    {
        if (compound.bytes.bytes[7] >= 0x80)
            return compound.bytes.bytes;
        return compound.string.m_string;
    }
```

From the Visual Studio watcher I know that compound.bytes.bytes[7] is 0x82 (the string is "hi"). So it should be 0x82 >= 0x80 as in true and return the bytes, yet for some reason this comparison get false and returns the char* of a normal string, which is of course a bogus pointer (0xcc006968 to be precise).

Also worth pointing out is that this very code still works correctly for normal strings.

What am I missing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because 0x80 is a negative char (remember, the char type is signed, at least on your platform).

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal, verifiable example? The behavior you're describing is pretty weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value 0x80 is a negative number when using **signed 8-bit integers**.  <s>Thus 0x82 would be less because it is also negative.</s> The value 0x82 translates to -126 and 0x80 translates to -128, which means the 0x80 is less than 0x82 **in twos complement signed integers**.

Switch your data type to `uint8_t`.

Comment: @Nikita:  Convert the hex values 0x80 and 0x82 to twos complement representation, assuming an 8-bit quantity, and see if it overflows.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being really dumb, but isn't 0x80 = -128 and 0x82 = -126? So 0x80 would still be less than 0x82? Taking it to the extreme, 0xFF would be -1, and 0x80 < 0xFF.

Comment: @templatetypedef:  My bad, you are correct.  I'll edit my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: The *keyboard* is behaving badly today. ;-)  Made another edit.

Comment: But the issue the OP is reporting is that they see 0x82 somewhere, they're stepping through the code in a debugger, and they're seeing the comparison 0x82 >= 0x80 happening, but the comparison returns false. It seems like the explanation you're providing says that the issue has to do with signedness, but even with signedness the comparison should still evaluate to true. How would the change you're proposing address this?

Comment: this is wrong. The comparison is done in `int` due to default promotion, so that line actually compares -126 vs 128, not -126 and -128

Answer (score 2):

char* is signed  0x80 and beyond are negative

Comment: The `char` type can be `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`, depending on the compiler settings.

Comment: Only a sadist would change the sign of char with a compiler setting.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with signed values (char). So, 0x80 means -128, and 0x82 means -126. This code may work as you need:

```
inline const char* c_str(void) const
{
    if (static_cast<unsigned char>(compound.bytes.bytes[7]) >= 0x80u)
        return compound.bytes.bytes;
    return compound.string.m_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing signed char (0x82 = -126) to signed int (0x00000080 = 128). Signed char can be a number from -128 to 127, so it will be always less than 128.